# Goland - Unresolved dependency

Tags: go, goland

I want the goland to find the dependencies that I installed using `go get`

It was working but now when I open it marks as unresolved

[image]

I already tried `go mod tidy` but it didn't work

Comment: Do not post images of text.

Comment: But do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Make sure that _Go modules integration_ is enabled in _Preferences | Go | Go modules_.

Comment: s0xzwasd, that that was the problem. Thank You. If you put the answer I will check as correct

Comment: [Disable the `Enable Go modules integration`. And enable it again](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-12228)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open settings in goland

[image]

make sure Enable Go modules integration is toggled

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to sync dependencies as follow [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/create-a-project-with-go-modules-integration.html#synchronize-dependencies-from-go-mod)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa7fN.png)

And make sure you specified the location of your Go installation in `$GOROOT`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).